# how to calculate the height of an activity excluding the status bar, toolbar/actionbar and bottom navigationview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a scenario where I need to set the height of a recycler view cell in such a way that all the items say 4, should be visible in the screen completely. in order to achieve that I need to know the size of the screen excluding those bars. Is it possible to calculate the height prior to setting the recycler view adapter so that no further refresh is required?

Comment: well for calculate size we need to have a layout then we calculate the size of layout, i think you should use better design so your `RecycleView` can be match_parent

Answer (score 0):

For that give every item the weight of '1', using `android:layout_weight="1"` This way every view will be given same width and height.
NOTE: But for `android:layout_weight="1"` to be applied you have to make every item in the recycler view's width and height `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

You just needs to find the height of the view which contains the height and divide that height by 4 also apply that height to the recycle view row.

Make sure your layout which contains recycle view must be match parent and recycle view also needs to be match parent.

Code to calculate height:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int width = mView.getWidth();
            int height = mView.getHeight();
        }
}
```